# What are the ways to improve testlink performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, testlink

We have testlink 1.9.8 running on a **Windows Server 2008 Virtual machine**.
I would like to improve the performance of testlink. What are the techniques I should use to improve the performance.

Server Configurations

- Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1
- 8GB RAM
- 15GB free disk space
- XAMPP V 3.2.1
- about 4Gb mysql database

in my.ini the following values are set for the mySQL server

- key_buffer = 512M
- max_allowed_packet = 64M
- sort_buffer_size = 4096K
- net_buffer_length = 16K
- read_buffer_size = 4096K
- read_rnd_buffer_size = 2048K
- myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M

Can someone give me an advice on improving the performance of testlink.

Comment: Testlink is a web based test management tool. And it is open source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance almost always boils down to one or two queries that perform poorly.  From them I branch into, often in *this* order:

- Indexes
- Formulation of the queries
- Schema design
- Engine and cache for that engine
- Hardware

What you have presented comes from the opposite order, and has not gotten to the useful stuff.